# Asymptotes in a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using TikZ to plotting some functions for a document. For example, I want to plot 1/(x+1). So I did something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
\draw (0,5) node[above]{\fimg $y=f(x+1)=\dfrac{1}{x+1}$};
\clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
\ejes[1]{-4}{4}{-4}{4}
\draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{1/(\x+1)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

where `\ejes[style]{xmin}{xmax}{ymin}{ymax}` is command, that I have defined before to draw the axes (join with `\fimg`). My expected output for the code below was just the function, but I get this:

[image]

So, TikZ automagically put the vertical asymptote at x=-1. That isn't a bad thing, but now I want to have some control over it. For example I want dotted lines for vertical asymptotes. How can I do that?

Comment: Please only one question per question post.

Comment: Got it @MartinScharrer.

Comment: that is the wrong graphic if you say `f(x+1)`. It is the output of `f(x)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TikZ doesn't actually draw the asymptotes: it simply connects the two points immediately before and after the jump. Because you use so many samples, you don't see that the line is actually slightly slanted.

Two suggestions: For drawing the plots, I would use the PGFplots package, which extends the plotting capabilities of TikZ/PGF substantially. It allows you to filter out coordinates above or below a certain threshold, and interrupt the plot line at that point. For drawing the asymptotes, I would use a normal `\draw` command. If you use PGFplots, you can specify the line in terms of the "data coordinate system" and in terms of the "axis coordinate system", so you can draw a vertical line that runs from the bottom of the plot at a specified horizontal coordinate to the top of the plot.

I've defined a new style `ejes=<xmin>:<xmax> <ymin>:<ymax>` which sets all the required parameters and draws the axes, and a new command `\vasymptote{<xpos>}` which draws a vertical dashed line at the desired position. It takes an optional argument which will be passed to the line, so you can change the color or thickness or dash pattern as you please.

With the style and the command, you could recreate your first image using

```
\tikz{\begin{axis}[ejes=-4:4 -4:4, title={$y=f(x+1)=\dfrac{1}{x+1}$}]
    \addplot {1/(x+1)};
    \vasymptote {-1}
\end{axis}}
```

which will yield

[image]

Here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\vasymptote}[2][]{
    \draw [densely dashed,#1] ({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:#2,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:#2,0});
}

\pgfplotsset{
    double y domain/.code 2 args={
        \pgfmathsetmacro\doubleymin{#1*2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\doubleymax{#2*2}
    },
    ejes/.style args={#1:#2 #3:#4}{
        double y domain={#3}{#4},
        domain=#1:#2,
        ymin=#3,ymax=#4, restrict y to domain=\doubleymin:\doubleymax,
        samples=100,
        enlargelimits=false,
        axis lines=middle,
        xtick={#1,...,#2}, ytick={#3,...,#4},
        xticklabels=\empty, yticklabels=\empty,
        every axis plot post/.style={
            black,
            mark=none,
            smooth
        },
        scale only axis,
        width=4cm,
        height=4cm
    }
}


\tikz{\begin{axis}[ejes=-4:4 -4:4,title={$y=f(x+1)=\dfrac{1}{x+1}$}]
    \addplot {1/(x+1)};
    \vasymptote {-1}
\end{axis}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could also implement this as a key to `axis` by `\pgfplotsset{vasymptote/.style={before end axis/.append code={\draw[densely dashed] ({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:#1,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:#1,0});}}`.  Maybe could even get the optional argument the style declaration.

Comment: How would you create a similar `\hasymptote` command?

Comment: @Jake If I pass `color=red` for the first parameter of `\vasymptote` I get 'Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function 'color' (in 'color=red').'

Comment: What part of this prevents incorrect tracing of the asymptote?

Comment: I had a similar question to @Xenon and made it: `\newcommand{\hasymptote}[2][]{
    \draw [densely dashed,color=blue,ultra thick,#1] ({rel axis cs:0,0} |- {axis cs:0,#2}) -- ({rel axis cs:1,0} |- {axis cs:0,#2});
}`
Note I added my own options in the command, because I too get an error like @GeoffPointer

I used https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401429/139678 to help me understand.

Answer (score 6):

With PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\def\f(#1){1/(#1)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(2,4)   
    \psline[linecolor=gray,linestyle=dashed](-1,-4)(-1,3.5)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-4,-4)(1.5,3.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psset{algebraic,linecolor=blue}
    \psplot{-3.5}{-1.3}{\f(x+1)}
    \psplot{-0.7}{1}{\f(x+1)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT:

Based on the comment given by [texenthusiast](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15717) below,

> I upvoted thinking your answer is different from Herbert's as i have
>   no idea. It would be better to mention it what's the difference.

here are the differences:

- I used the default `plotpoints=50`. It should be enough. Increasing this value makes the resulting PDF bigger in file size.
- I split the graph into 2 parts with the asymptotic line as the separator. I chose an offset of 0.3 (by inspection) to shift the domain a bit to avoid too large `y` values.  For the current PSTricks implementation, the end points of the asymptotic graph near its asymptotic line oscillate. Fluctuation can be controlled by `plotpoints` key. Splitting it into 2 parts and offsetting the domain freeing me from increasing `plotpoints` from its default. Herbert used a single `\psplot` but  with `plotpoints=1000` to minimize the fluctuation. Thus the differences are pessimistic and optimistic approaches.

Comment: I upvoted thinking your answer is different from Herbert's as i have no idea. It would be better to mention it what's the difference..

Answer (score 4):

Alternative approach to plot asymptote using [gnuplottex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex) package with automatic underhood [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)  computation.

**Works with: `-shell-escape` enabled  and `gnuplot 4.4`**,

**code compiled with:  pdflatex,frozen texlive distro 2012 on Linux**

self descriptive gnuplot code:

```
\documentclass[preview=true,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex
% amsmath for math labels
% code compiled with pdflatex engine via frozen texlive 2012 on Linux  
\usepackage{gnuplottex,amsmath} % need shell-escape enabled and gnuplot 4.4
\begin{document} 
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]
                                        # means comments in gnuplot syntax
  unset border                          # border off
  unset grid                            # grid off
  unset key                             # dataset legends off
  set format x ''                       # xtics without labels
  set format y ''                       # ytics without labels
  set size square                       # figure into square size
  # xy co-ordinates range
  xmin=-3;xmax=3;ymin=-15;ymax=15;
  set samples 100                       # no of divisions xaxis xmin to  xmax
  set zeroaxis                          # x axis and y-axis aligned to origin
  set xrange [xmin:xmax]                # plot range x and y
  set yrange [ymin:ymax]
  set arrow from xmin,0 to xmax,0  filled   # xaxis starting (x,y) to ending
  set arrow from 0,ymin to 0,ymax  filled   # yaxis starting to ending
  # dotted line at discontinuity
  set arrow from -1,ymin to -1,ymax  nohead linestyle 2 linewidth 3 linecolor rgb 'black' 
  set xtics axis                        # x major ticks 
  set ytics axis                        # y major ticks 
  set title 'Asymptote $y=f(x+1)=\dfrac{1}{x+1}$ function in gnuplot'
  #set xlabel "$x$"
  #set ylabel "$f(x+1)$" rotate by 0 offset 20 
                                         # Piecewise func with ternary operator
  a(x) = x<-1  ? 1.0/(x+1) : 1/0         #  continous in x < -1
  #b(x) = x=-1  ?      inf    : 1/0      #  will not plot at discontinous x= -1
  c(x) = x>-1  ? 1.0/(x+1) : 1/0         #  continous in x > -1
  plot a(x) linetype 1 linewidth 3 linecolor rgb 'gray',c(x) linetype 1 linewidth 3 linecolor rgb 'gray'
\end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

**output:**

[image]

Comment: `\frac{1}{x+1}` without `()` should be enough.

Comment: @Bugbusters  Thanks,`\dfrac{}{}` seems to be better,

Comment: @MatthewLeingang hope you had chance to see [erf function in pgfplots gnuplot matlab](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108620/15717) i am trying out options.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Why not to plot a vertical asymptote with the `Asymptote`?
A slight modification of the `Asymptote` example `1overx.asy`,
`1overxplus1.asy`:

```
import graph;
import math; // needed for drawline()
size(250,IgnoreAspect);

texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}"  // for the text font
+"\usepackage{amsmath}");           // for the \dfrac

real f(real x) {return 1/(x+1);};

real xmin=-4.8;
real xmax=3.8;

real epsi=1e-2;

bool3 branch(real x)  // an extended boolean type that can take on the values true, default, or false.
                      //A bool3 type can be cast to or from a bool. 
{
  static int lastsign=0;
  if(abs(x+1)<epsi) return false;
  int sign=sgn(x+1);
  bool b=lastsign == 0 || sign == lastsign; 
  lastsign=sign;
  if(b){
    return true;
  }else{
    return default;
  }
}

pen lowBranchPen=blue+1.2pt;
pen highBranchPen=red+1.2pt;
pen dashed=linetype(new real[] {4,3}); // set up dashed pattern
pen asyPen=olive+dashed+1pt;

guide[] g=graph(f,-4.8,2.8,branch);  // returns an array of curve branches according to branch function
draw(g[0],lowBranchPen);
draw(g[1],highBranchPen);
drawline((-1,-1),(-1,1),asyPen);    // draws a visible portion of the (infinite) line 
                                    // going through two points 

xaxis("$x$",LeftTicks(Label(LeftSide),NoZero));
yaxis("$y$",RightTicks(Label(RightSide),NoZero,Step=3,step=1.5));

label("$f(x)=\dfrac1{x+1}$",(-3,9));
```

Run `asy -f pdf 1overxplus1.asy` to get a standalone `1overxplus1.pdf`.

Answer (score 3):

with PSTricks (run with `xelatex`)

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4.25,-4.25)(4.25,4.25)
\psaxes[labels=none,ticksize=0 4pt]{->}(0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
\psplot[algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=blue,yMaxValue=4,plotpoints=1000]{-4}{4}{1/(x+1)}
\psline[linestyle=dashed](-1,-4)(-1,4)
\rput(2,3){$\displaystyle f(x)=\frac1{x+1}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if one wants *exactly* min/max values for the function then it can be clipped:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4.25,-4.25)(4.25,4.25)
\psaxes[labels=none,ticksize=0 4pt]{->}(0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
\psclip{\psframe[linestyle=none](-4,-4)(4,4)}
\psplot[algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=blue,yMaxValue=4.5,plotpoints=1000]{-4}{4}{1/(x+1)}
\endpsclip
\psline[linestyle=dashed](-1,-4)(-1,4)
\rput(2,3){$\displaystyle f(x)=\frac1{x+1}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

However, it's often not needed!

Comment: is it possible to remove labels on axis as OP had in Q ?

Comment: sure, `\psaxes[labels=none]{->}...`

Comment: there is [only one demo](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Gnuplot/gnuplot) of using gnuplot with pstricks, do you have any of them hosted anywhere ? because some of features of gnuplot are good enough to show some demo. Also there is not much mentioned in pstricks manual except ref 24. I will have a look at pst-plot as well.

Comment: @texenthusiast: no, there are no more examples and yes, `gnuplot` is really powerful but has a lousy output

Comment: @Herbert in what way `lousy` means, legends, fonts,labels etc but with the terminal advancements (latex,pstricks pdf epslatex tikz etc), it looks better. see my answer for this Q. In pstricks documentation do you have something written about calling gnuplot from pst-plot like `\addplot gnuplot{}` handle to help newbies understand.

Comment: @texenthusiast: the _default_ ticks, labels, fonts, ... There is no difference in running the external gnuplot from within tikZ or PSTricks. Nobody did it for PSTricks until now, that's all.

Comment: Even though `linestyle=none`, the `\psframe` as the clipper still depends on `linewidth` unless you change `dimen` from `outer` (default) to `middle`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The datavisualization Tikz library now allows us to add horizontal and vertical asymptotes to a function plot in an easy way.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization[
    school book axes,
    visualize as smooth line/.list={left,right},
    x axis={length=6cm, ticks and grid={major also at=-1}},
    y axis={length=6cm, ticks={some}},
    data/format=function
  ]
    data[set=left] {
      var x : interval [-4:-1.1] samples 42;
      func y = 1 / (\value x + 1);
    }
    data[set=right] {
      var x : interval[-0.9:4] samples 42;
      func y = 1 / (\value x + 1);
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that as the domain is not continuous, I had to split the function in two distinct parts.

[image]

Comment: What is the actual thing that adds the line? Is it automatic?

Comment: It's on the x axis specification : I add a tick and a grid line on -1. Note that you can easily change the style of this line (in case you want to add a regular grid to the plot).