# Erf function in LaTeX

Tags: pgfmath

Is there a way to easily compute [the erf function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution) (or the cumulative distribution function of the normal law) in LaTeX?

Currently, I use `pgf` to make computation, but I did not find a way to compute erf using `pgf`.

I would be happy to use any package that is available to compute erf, or any custom solution to compute that function.

Comment: These references might help you: [How to Draw CDF of normal distribution in Tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60950/13304) and [Draw a bivariate normal distribution in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31708/13304). Actually, there are other useful answers (I've read another interesting one by Jake, but I can't find it now) on the site: perhaps a deeper search is worth.

Comment: I don't want to draw the function, I want to compute and typeset the values. I read that link, but it's not really useful for what I need. Thanks

Comment: @Xoff You can create a `pgfmath` function very easily with the Taylor expression of the erf function. The precision won't be that good anyway as TeX is not meant for math. (Although certain floating point packages/libraries may help here to a certain degree.)

Comment: Sure, I can do it myself. But as it's a very common function in some mathematical area, I hope someone already did something good to compute it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For precise values, I recommend externalizing the calculation, here `gnuplot` is used.

### Code (needs `--shell-escape` enabled)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pgfmath,pgffor}
\makeatletter
\def\qrr@split@result#1 #2\@qrr@split@result{\edef\erfInput{#1}\edef\erfResult{#2}}
\newcommand*{\gnuplotErf}[2][\jobname.eval]{%
    \immediate\write18{gnuplot -e "set print '#1'; print #2, erf(#2);"}%
    \everyeof{\noexpand}
    \edef\qrr@temp{\@@input #1 }%
    \expandafter\qrr@split@result\qrr@temp\@qrr@split@result
}
\makeatother
\DeclareMathOperator{\erf}{erf}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {-50,...,50}{%
\pgfmathparse{\x/50}%
\gnuplotErf{\x/50.}%
$ x = \pgfmathresult = \erfInput, \erf(x) = \erfResult$\par
}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Here is a comparison of [cjorssen](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107439/16595)’s (good!) [answer and `gnuplot`’s values](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DbDiS.png)

Comment: I get a strange error: `runsystem(gnuplot -e "set print 'erf.eval'; print -50/50., erf(-50/50.);")...quotation error in system command` (tl2012, debian)? Never had it before.

Comment: It's fixed in the CVS version but `pgfmath,pgffor` is not enough to compile in v2.10 official release. One needs to load `pgf,pgffor` to get everything otherwise `pgfkeys` etc. don't work. There was a dependency leak which was fixed some time ago in the CVS version.

Answer (score 22):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/457805/1195799).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{erf}{1}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfmathparse{#1 > 0 ? 1 : -1}%
    \edef\sign{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{abs(#1)}%
    \edef\x{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(1+0.3275911*\x)}%
    \edef\t{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{%
      1 - (((((1.061405429*\t -1.453152027)*\t) + 1.421413741)*\t 
      -0.284496736)*\t + 0.254829592)*\t*exp(-(\x*\x))}%
    \edef\y{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{(\sign)*\y}%
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale = 3]
  \draw[very thick,->] (-5,0) -- node[at end,below] {$x$}(5,0);
  \draw[very thick,->] (0,-1) -- node[below left] {$0$} node[at end,
  left] {$erf(x)$} (0,1);
  \draw[red,thick] plot[domain=-5:5,samples=200] (\x,{erf(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I up this answer, thank you. I was hoping something more precise was implemented.

Comment: @Xoff You can also use the `gnuplot` engine to plot in TikZ/`pgfplots`.

Comment: @Xoff That formula (7.1.26. in *A Handbook of Mathematical Functions* by Abramowitz and Stegun) has an error bounded by `$1.5 \times 10^{-7}$`.  I don't think it's possible to get closer in TeX.

Comment: Please add the definition of error function you are plotting?

Answer (score 16):

Using the [same approximation idea as cjorssen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107439/13450) (I tried the Taylor series as Qrrbrbirlbel suggested but it's pretty hopeless to get a decent approximation this way) I rewrote the function without using low-level PGF. Because we have so many 2D plots here already, I'll just use my 3D plot that I had already.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{
colormap={bluewhite}{ color(0cm)=(rgb:red,18;green,64;blue,171); color(1cm)=(white)}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={erf(\x)=%
      (1+(e^(-(\x*\x))*(-265.057+abs(\x)*(-135.065+abs(\x)%
      *(-59.646+(-6.84727-0.777889*abs(\x))*abs(\x)))))%
      /(3.05259+abs(\x))^5)*(\x>0?1:-1);},
    declare function={erf2(\x,\y)=erf(\x)+erf(\y);}
]
\begin{axis}[
    small,
    colormap name=bluewhite,
    width=\textwidth,
    enlargelimits=false,
    grid=major,
    domain=-3:3,
    y domain=-3:3,
    samples=33,
    unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
    view={20}{20},
    colorbar,
    colorbar style={
        at={(1,-.15)},
        anchor=south west,
        height=0.25*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/parent axis height},
    }
]
\addplot3 [surf,shader=faceted] {erf2(x,y)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3D plot of erf(x)+erf(y)]

The approximation has a maximum error of 1.5·10<sup>-7</sup> ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Approximation_with_elementary_functions)).

Thanks to [Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2552/jake) for [spotting and fixing](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9964403#9964403) the wrong syntax I first had in this code.

Answer (score 8):

A little late, but here's a solution using the `sagetex` package, which gives you the power of the (free) computer algebra system known as [Sage](http://sagemath.org/index.html). Sage has an error function command which, [according to the documentation](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/functions/sage/functions/special.html) is 1-erf. This code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
Sage has an error function command that's equal to $1-\mbox{erf}$. Here's     $\sage{error_fcn(2)}$ and 
$\sage{1-error_fcn(2)}$. There is an erf command but it doesn't seem to be   working properly 
in my older version of Sage. The formatting in Sage goes like this:   $\sage{n(error_fcn(2),digits=6)}$ 
and $\sage{n((1-error_fcn(2)),digits=11)}$. 
\begin{sagesilent}
g(x)=erf(x)
q=plot(g,x,-3,3,color='red')
\end{sagesilent}

This is a plot of $\mbox{erf}(x)$.
\begin{center}
\sageplot[scale=.35]{q}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

creates this output:
[image]

Comment: I did not find a way to get this package with texlive. Did  I miss something ?

Comment: You need to install Sage on your computer. The download link is [here](http://sagemath.org/download-linux.html). Once you installed you just need to copy sagetex.sty to the place where you latex your document: see [here](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/installation/sagetex.html) and [here](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/sagetex.html) for more details. Sagetex and TexLive mentioned at 2nd "here" link.

Answer (score 7):

Error function `erf(x)` computation and figure anatomy (axes,legends and labels) have been rendered in three approaches.

1. Fully `gnuplot`
2. `pgfplots` invokes `gnuplot`
3. Fully `Matlab`

Already there are good answers for example by Qrrbrbirlbel and cjorssen, both exploit pgfmath at macro level.

**1. Fully `gnuplot`**

Error function `erf(x)` computation in gnuplot with axes, legends and labels rendered in gnuplot `epslatex` terminal. The gnuplot terminal output is embedded automatically with [gnuplottex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex) package. `terminal=pdf` does not render Math labels hence `epslatex` terminal was used.

```
\documentclass[preview=true,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\begin{document} 
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]
  set grid
  set size square
  set key left 
  set title 'Error function in gnuplot  $ erf(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}\, dt$'
  set samples 50
  set xlabel "$x$"
  set ylabel "$erf(x)$"
  plot [-3:3] [-1:1] erf(x) title 'gnuplot' linetype 1 linewidth 3
\end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

**1) gnuplot output figure**
[image]

**2. `pgfplots` invokes `gnuplot`**

Error function `erf(x)` computation in gnuplot invoked by pgfplots and axes, legends, labels are rendered by pgfplots

```
\documentclass[preview=true,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$erf(x)$,title= {Error function in pgfplots $erf(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}\, dt$},legend style={draw=none},legend pos=north west,grid=major,enlargelimits=false]
\addplot [domain=-3:3,samples=50,red,no markers] gnuplot[id=erf]{erf(x)};
% Note: \addplot function { gnuplot code } is alias for \addplot gnuplot { gnuplot code };
\legend{pgfplots-gnuplot}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**2. pgfplots(gnuplot backend)output figure**

[image]

**3) Fully `Matlab`**

Error function $erf(x)$ computation in Matlab with axes,legends,labels rendered using [matlabfrag](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21286-matlabfrag)(psfrag tag based) and [mlf2pdf](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28545) functions.

**Note:** Fonts are frozen in PDF figure unlike the above approaches, but can be changed in `mlf2pdf.m` before generating them.

**`erf(x)` Matlab Script using mlf2pdf(matlabfrag as backend) to generate pdf **

```
clear all
clc
% Plotting section
    set(0,'DefaultFigureColor','w','DefaultTextFontName','Times','DefaultTextFontSize',12,'DefaultTextFontWeight','bold','DefaultAxesFontName','Times','DefaultAxesFontSize',12,'DefaultAxesFontWeight','bold','DefaultLineLineWidth',2,'DefaultLineMarkerSize',8);

% x and y data
x=linspace(-3,3,50);
y=erf(x);

figure(1);plot(x,y,'r');
grid on
axis([-3 3 -1 1]);
xlabel('$x$','Interpreter','none');
ylabel('$erf(x)$','Interpreter','none');
legend('Matlab');legend('boxoff');
title('Error function in Matlab $erf(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}\, dt$','Interpreter','none');
mlf2pdf(gcf,'error-func-fig');
```

**3. Output Figure**
[image]

`gnuplot 4.4`,`pgfplots 1.8` and `pdflatex -shell-escape` engine were used.

Comment: I went ahead with the second implementation here. I had to figure out something very simple but that wasn't working at the beginning. You have to call pdflatex with a special option like this: pdflatex -shell-escape yourfile.tex; also, you need to have gnuplot installed, which I didn't know I didn't have.  Other than that. A great solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the FFI in LuaJITTeX (and LuaTeX ≥ 1.0.3) to access the `erf` function in `libm` directly.  The performance and accuracy are simply amazing!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\directlua{
local ffi = require("ffi")
ffi.cdef[[
double erf(double arg);
]]
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{erf}{1}{%
  \edef\pgfmathresult{%
    \directlua{tex.print(ffi.C.erf(\pgfmathfloatvalueof{#1}))}%
  }%
}

\DeclareMathOperator\erf{erf}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    no marks, samples=101,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$\erf(x)$},
    ]
    \addplot {erf(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really nice trick! One naive question: how does luatex/ffi knows where to look for (here `libm`)?

Comment: @cjorssen The FFI just resolves symbols like a compiler.  Because `libm` is statically linked into LuaTeX (at least in vanilla TeX Live), you can access it via `ffi.C`.  If the symbol comes from a DSO, you have to load it first using `ffi.load` and then resolve the symbol name through this handle.  You can have a look at these two answers of mine for examples: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/403794, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/408014

Comment: Hi, can you write it to LuaLatex??? thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

PSTricks solution, using package `pst-ode`, command `\pstODEsolve`.

The integral is thought of as an initial value problem and solved (integrated) numerically between 0 and *x* using RKF45 method with automatic stepsize control.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=5pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-ode,pst-plot}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% erf
% #1: x
% #2: PS variable for result list
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\erf(#1)#2{%
  \pstODEsolve[algebraicAll]{retVal}{ %`retval' takes initial value and erf(#1)
    2/sqrt(Pi)*y[0] %post-multiply result of integration with 2/sqrt(Pi)
  }{0}{#1}{ % integration interval
    2 % two output points (at t=0 and t=#1)
  }{
    0.0 % initial value at t=0
  }{Euler^(-t^2)} %integrand
  %
  %  initialise, if necessary, empty solution list given as arg #2
  \pstVerb{/#2 where {pop}{/#2 {} def} ifelse}
  %  From `retVal', we throw away result at t=0, and append x (arg #1) and erf(x) to our
  %  solution list (arg #2):
  \pstVerb{/#2 [#2 #1 retVal exch pop] cvx def}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%solve function integral, 121 plotpoints: -3, -2.95, ..., 2.95, 3
\multido{\nx=-3.00+0.05}{121}{
  \erf(\nx){erf} %result appended to solution list `erf'
}

%plot result
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-1)(0.2,6.2)
  \psset{xAxisLabel=$x$,yAxisLabel=$\mathrm{erf}(x)$,xAxisLabelPos={c,-0.3},yAxisLabelPos={-1,c}}
  \begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=frame,Oy=-1,Ox=-3,Dx=1,Dy=0.5](-3,-1)(-3,-1)(3,1){8cm}{6cm}
  \listplot[linecolor=red]{erf}
  \end{psgraph}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```