# How can I define a mathematical function as a LaTeX macro?

Tags: pstricks, calculations, pst-plot

I am attempting to create a usable function within LaTeX such that its inputs are transformed mathematically. However, I cannot find any documentation that can perform such mathematical function definition.

Here is an example of what I am seeking:

Having defined a function entitled `\myMathFunction` which accepts only one parameter, the follow usage:

```
\myMathFunction{2}
```

should output 6 if the function is defined as follows: `({#1} * 5) - {#1}^2`

Where `{#1}` is the parameter, and in the case of my example, is equal to `2`.

Additionally, the function should be usable within a PSTricks plot. E.g.

```
\psplot[
    algebraic,
    linecolor   = red,
    linewidth   = 1pt
]{0}{TwoPi}
{\myMathFunction{x}}
```

Comment: The math capabilities of (La)TeX are rather limited. You can look at the `l3fp` module of `expl3` (`texdoc interface3`), or at PGF.

Comment: Using PGF (you need to load the `tikz` package), you can do the following: `\newcommand\myMathFunction[1]{\pgfmathparse{5*#1 - (#1)^2}\pgfmathresult}
\myMathFunction{2}`.

Comment: Gnuplot can be used, too: [Erf function in LaTex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107423/16595)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A calculated table and the plotted curve:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn%% allow _ : as a letter
\newcommand\myMathFunction[1]{% 
  \ifx#1x ((#1) * 5) - (#1)^2  
  \else \fp_to_decimal:n {((#1) * 5) - (#1)^2} \fi}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ r r }
$x$ & $f(x)$ \\\hline
0 & \myMathFunction{0}\\
1 & \myMathFunction{1}\\
2 & \myMathFunction{2}\\
3.3 & \myMathFunction{3.3}\\
4 & \myMathFunction{4}\\
5 & \myMathFunction{5}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
%
\pspicture[shift=*](-1,0)(6,7)
\psaxes{->}(5.5,6)
\psplot[algebraic,linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt]{0}{5}{\myMathFunction{x}}
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: just to clarify: only the `tabular` uses the `l3fp` code, right? the pspicture is just using its in-grained parsing and computation of algebraic expressions?

Comment: sure, how else should it work?

Comment: generating data which would then be plotted via the services of the pspicture. Perhaps the user has a macro which does computations not easily feasible via postscript code. For example the sum from `n=x` to `n=x+1000` of the `n th` digits of π (random example, perhaps `pstricks` does that !!)

Answer (score 40):

## Remarks

I used the powerful LaTeX3 featureset `l3fp`, which is automatically loaded by `xparse`.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myMathFunction}{m}
    { \fp_to_decimal:n {((#1) * 5) - (#1)^2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\myMathFunction{2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 33):

Here is a TikZ/PGF solution.

I'm not sure how it compares to [the `l3fp` approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147894/21891), but it definitely offers more flexibility than a low-level [TeX approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147896/21891) because

- it works in fixed-point arithmetic, not just with integers, and
- by using the right PGFkeys, you can easily customise how the result should be printed (trailing zeros, scientific notation, etc.). I refer you to section 66: *Number printing* of the [PFG manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) for more details on that.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% definiton
\newcommand\myMathFunction[1]%
{%
    \pgfmathparse{5*#1-(#1)^2}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}%
}

% macro calls
\myMathFunction{2} \quad
\myMathFunction{45} \quad
\myMathFunction{-56}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd keep the PGFkeys call local, or at least move it outside of `\myMathFunction`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I think I'll leave it inside the definition, but I'll make it local.

Comment: Instead give the options to `\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=3]{...}` then you don't need `pgfkeys`

Comment: @percusse *fixed* (pun intended)

Answer (score 31):

In good old (Plain) TeX, i.e., without LaTeX, with the proper TeX syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcount\pom % temporary
\newcount\kw % square
\newcount\first % first

\def\myMathFunction#1{\pom#1  \first\pom \kw\pom  
\multiply\kw by\pom \multiply\first by5 
\advance\first by-\kw \the\first}

\myMathFunction{2}


And an example of loop:

\newcount\n
\n-10
\loop \ifnum\n<10 $f(\the\n)=\myMathFunction{\n}$ \advance\n by1 \repeat

\end{document}
```

[image]

We could do it using just two counters, but this solution is easier to understand. Numbers are integers, with the absolute value less than 2^31 on all stages of computing.

Comment: Probably much faster than any other approach (for if someone decided to solve Finite Elements in LeTeX...)

Comment: @Przemyslaw This solution only works for integers, right? As far as I know, TeX's count registers only accept integers.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, with restrictions as in the last sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 25):

Here's a solution using **LuaLaTeX**. The MWE provides a LaTeX-side macro called `\MyMathFunction` that interfaces with a Lua-side function called `mymathfunction`; the latter does the actual computations.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for '\ensuremath' macro
\usepackage{luacode}    % for 'luacode' environment

% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}
   function mymathfunction( x )
      return 5*x - x^2  -- specify the function you need
   end
\end{luacode}

%TeX-side macro that invokes the Lua function
\newcommand{\MyMathFunction}[1]{%
    \ensuremath{\directlua{tex.sprint( mymathfunction ( #1 ) )}}}

\begin{document}
The value of my math function evaluated at 2 is \MyMathFunction{2}.

\newcommand\myval{6}  % macro that contains parameter value
The value of my math function evaluated at \myval\ is \MyMathFunction{\myval}.

\end{document}
```

Observe that the value of `\myval` could itself be the result of a calculation done in Lua. For example, you could execute

```
\newcommand\myval{ \directlua{ tex.sprint( math.exp(1) ) } }
```

to set `\myval` equal to the base of the natural logarithms. And, one could pass the result of a calculation done in Lua directly to `\MyMathFunction`, i.e., without setting up a macro called `\myval` to contain the result of the calculation. For instance,

```
\MyMathFunction{ \directlua{ tex.sprint( math.sqrt(2) ) }}
```

will evaluate `\MyMathFunction` at the square root of 2.

Comment: Actually, the `\ifx` trick was initially proposed by Herbert in his answer here.

Comment: @HenriMenke - Thanks for this clarification, I'll edit my answer to provide the correct attribution.

Comment: @Mico just to clarify: within the pspicture, at no point is the luacode ever executed, it is `pst-plot` which handles the whole thing, right?

Comment: also, `\ifx#1x` appears dangerous, what if `#1` is `11`? shouldn't one do `\ifx x#1` rather?

Comment: @jfbu I thought, that `\ifx` was comparing tokens, while `\if` was expanding tokens before comparison.

Comment: @HenriMenke  yes `\ifx` does not expand, but if I do `\MyMathFunction {11}` then the true branch is chosen, and this is not wanted.

Comment: @HenriMenke the `#1` is not expanded but it is replaced by the tokens it represents, thus possible `11` meaning two successive identical (unexpanded, but here they are unexpandable anyhow) tokens and then `\ifx` test is positive.

Comment: @jfbu - On further investigation, you're right about the way the `\ifx` clause was set up in the second example (with `\psplot`), the "false" branch -- i.e., the part that invoked the lua code -- was never called. In consequence, I've removed the entire addendum part of the answer.

Answer (score 18):

Using [PythonTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pythontex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\newcommand{\MyMathFunction}[1]{\py{2*(#1)**3 - 7}}

\begin{document}
\MyMathFunction{2}
\end{document}
```

Suppose the above is the content of the file `my_math_fun_with_python.tex`.

You run LeTeX on the file:

```
latex my_math_fun_with_latex
```

then you run pythontex:

```
pythontex.py my_math_fun_with_latex
```

That will execute the python code in the file, and save the results.

Than you run LaTeX again:

```
latex my_math_fun_with_latex
```

Answer (score 10):

The [`fp` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp) provides a LaTeX2e-like interface to arithmetic:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\newcommand{\myMathFunction}[1]
    {\FPeval\result{trunc(((#1) * 5) - (#1)^2:0)}\result}
\begin{document}
\verb|\myMathFunction{2}|: \myMathFunction{2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

A much more general solution with the omnipotent Mathematica, LaTeX and PSTricks. In this answer I show how to

- evaluate a function,
- factor it into the product of linear real binomials,
- plot its graph.

### Step 1

Purchase Mathematica Home Edition (about USD $250), download and install it.

### Step 2

Create a template named `main.mtex` (for example). The extension `.mtex` is important because Mathematica uses "convention over configuration" philosophy.

```
% main.mtex
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{comment}
<* 
    f[x_] := x^2 - 5 x + 6;
    rep:= x_Times -> Infix[x, "*"];
*>
\end{comment}


\begin{document}
\section*{Problem}
Let $ y = f(x) = <* f[x] *>$,
\begin{enumerate}
    \item factor $f(x)$
    \item evaluate $f(\tfrac 1 2)$
    \item plot its graph.
\end{enumerate}

\section*{Solution}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $f(x) = <* Factor[f[x]] *>$
    \item $f(\tfrac 1 2)= <* f[1/2] *> $
    \item \hspace{20pt}
    \begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(5,3)
        \psaxes{->}(0,0)(0,-1)(4.5,2.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
        \psplot[algebraic,linecolor=blue]{1}{4}{<* f[x] /. rep *>}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Everything in `<* ... *>` contains Mathematica commands and they will be replaced by invoking `Splice` function that will be explained shortly.

### Step 3

Create an new Mathematica document named `Splicer.nb` (for example) as follows.

```
Splice["C:\\Users\\Donut E. Knot\\Documents\\main.mtex"];
```

And execute the command by pressing Shift+Enter. Mathematica will generate a file 
`main.tex` containing code as follows.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{comment}
\text{Null}
\end{comment}


\begin{document}
\section*{Problem}
Let $ y = f(x) = x^2-5 x+6$,
\begin{enumerate}
    \item factor $f(x)$
    \item evaluate $f(\tfrac 1 2)$
    \item plot its graph.
\end{enumerate}

\section*{Solution}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $f(x) = (x-3) (x-2)$
    \item $f(\tfrac 1 2)= \frac{15}{4} $
    \item \hspace{20pt}
    \begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(5,3)
        \psaxes{->}(0,0)(0,-1)(4.5,2.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
        \psplot[algebraic,linecolor=blue]{1}{4}{x^2+-5*x+6}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

### Step 4

Compile the `main.tex` with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` as it contains PSTricks code.
The output is...

[image]

### Step 5

Done. :-)

Comment: `f[x]//Factor` seems to be more readable.

Comment: Have you heard of Sweave? (Suggesting because 250 is a bit steep for some of us...)

It would essentially provide the free alternative to this. Statistics and mathematics calculations embedded in LaTeX

Comment: @EricR: The spent money does mean nothing when considering the power of Mathematica. I don't think Sweave can be used to substitute for Mathematica. :-)

Comment: I want to grant 100 bounties of 500 each to this answer. I really love it very very much.

Comment: @EricR you can ask your university. Some pay for you and then you can use a version for students.

Comment: Just to check if you deserve your `100x500` bounties: does the `pspicture` really use the mathematica evaluations or rather, like I believe is the case with other answers here including a `pst-plot`, the `pspicture` is done simply by `pstricks`? ah, sorry, I see that yours does not differ from the others in that respect. The point is: I read the OP as how does one get a plot of a function which `pstricks` is unable to compute

Answer (score 9):

My package 'calculus' (installed together with 'calculator') defines some commands to declare mathematical functions.
Unfortunately these functions can not be drawn using PSTricks, but you can draw it using my package 'xpicture".

Your example can be defined typing

```
\newqpoly{\myMathFunction}{0}{5}{-1}
```

(this declare the quadratic polynomial p(x)=0+5x-x^2). Then, you can compute this function and its derivative at x=2 by typing

```
\myMathFunction{2}{\sol}{\Dsol}
```

(\sol stores p(2); \Dsol stores p'(2)). Try

```
If $p(x)=-x^2+5x$, then $p(2)=\sol$ and $p'(2)=\Dsol$.
```

This code draw the graph:

```
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.75cm}
\begin{Picture}(-0.5,-10.5)(6.5,10.5)
   \cartesianaxes(0,-10)(\numberTWOPI,7)
   \PlotFunction{\myMathFunction}{0}{\numberTWOPI}
\end{Picture}
```

[image: Function graph]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7):

Another solution with [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), a free computer algebra system. Note: Only for Windows users.

### Step 1

Download and install Maxima.

### Step 2

Create a batch file named `cas.bat` (for example) as follows.

```
rem cas.bat
echo off
set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Maxima-5.31.2\bin"
maxima --very-quiet -r %1 > solution.tex
```

Save the batch in the same directory in which your input file below exists. It is just for the sake of simplicity.

### Step 3

Create the input file named `main.tex` (for example) as follows.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\f(#1){(#1)^2-5*(#1)+6}


\begin{document} 

\section{Problem}
Evaluate $\f(x)$ for $x=\frac 1 2$.

\section{Solution}
\immediate\write18{cas "x: 1/2\string$ tex(\f(x))\string$"}

\input{solution}

\end{document}
```

### Step 4

Compile the input file with `pdflatex -shell-escape main` and you will get a nice output as follows.

[image]

### Miscellaneous

Apparently the output of Maxima is as follows.

```
solution.tex
$${{15}\over{4}}$$
```

Answer (score 6):

For an expression with the basic operations and the square root extraction
[and also logic operators and conditional evaluation] you can use
`\xintNewExpr` or `\xintNewFloatExpr` from the
[xintexpr](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint) package to create a (completely
expandable) mathematical function.

The package core routines compute exactly, with an arbitrary number of digits, and natively with fractions too. The floating point routines compute with a user-specified precision. Default is with `16` digits.

The main limitation at the time of writing is that currently `sqrt` is the only non-rational operation permitted. Powers must be with integral exponents.

Macros defined via `\xintNewExpr` or `\xintNewFloatExpr` may be nested one within the other. This feature was
broken from release `1.09i` to release `1.09ka`, version `1.09kb` [just released at the time of writing] reverted the bug
which had been introduced in `1.09i`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\xintNewExpr \MathFunction [1] {#1 * 5 - #1^2}

\xintNewExpr \MathFunctionRounded [1] {round(#1*5 - #1^2,12)}

\xintNewExpr \MathFunctionRoundedBis [2] {round(#1*5 - #1^2,#2)}

\xintNewFloatExpr \MathFunctionFloat [1] {#1 * 5 - #1^2}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{verbatim}
\xintNewExpr \MathFunction [1] {#1 * 5 - #1^2}
\xintNewExpr \MathFunctionRounded [1] {round(#1*5 - #1^2,12)}
\xintNewExpr \MathFunctionRoundedBis [2] {round(#1*5 - #1^2,#2)}
\xintNewFloatExpr \MathFunctionFloat [1] {#1 * 5 - #1^2}
\end{verbatim}

\ttfamily

output in xint own fraction format:\newline
\verb|\MathFunction {12344321.56789876}->|\MathFunction {12344321.56789876}

\medskip

output as a fixed point number (12 digits after decimal mark):\newline
\verb|\MathFunctionRounded {12344321.56789876}->|\MathFunctionRounded
{12344321.56789876}

\medskip

output as a fixed point number (20 digits after decimal mark):\newline
\verb|\MathFunctionRoundedBis {12344321.56789876}{20}->|\MathFunctionRoundedBis
{12344321.56789876}{20}

\medskip

floating point number (16 digits of precision by default)\newline
\verb|\MathFunctionFloat {12344321.56789876}->|\MathFunctionFloat {12344321.56789876}

\medskip

floating point number (20 digits of precision; macro need not be redefined)\newline
\verb|\xintDigits := 20;|\xintDigits := 20;\newline
\verb|\MathFunctionFloat {12344321.56789876}->|\MathFunctionFloat {12344321.56789876}


\medskip

nesting of macros:\newline
\verb|\MathFunctionFloat {\MathFunctionFloat {12344321.56789876}}->|\MathFunctionFloat {\MathFunctionFloat {12344321.56789876}}

\medskip

\noindent\verb|\MathFunction {\MathFunction {12344321.56789876}}->|\newline
\MathFunction {\MathFunction {12344321.56789876}}

\medskip

\verb|\MathFunction has meaning| \newline
\meaning\MathFunction

\end{document}
```

[image: xintexpr advertisement]