# mathematics expression for parameter

Tags: parameters, subequations

I would like to use a number that is a fraction of one constant and one argument of function. I tried:

```
\newcommand{\myfunction}[1]{
\newcommand{\tailleimg}{0.95/#1}
}
```

But I get an error

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
```

Adding units after the fraction does not solve the problem. What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I define a mathematical function as a LaTeX macro?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147891/5764)

Comment: that code snippet doesn't throw such an error. Create a complete example.