# How to perform mathematical operation in latex?

Tags: lastpage

I am new to `LaTeX`. I'm working on some sample `LaTeX` examples. The sample I want to create a progress bar in my document. My sample code is shown below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[draft,subsubsection]{progress}
\renewcommand{\ProgressDocOutput}[1]{%
\vskip-0.6cm\ProgressDrawBar{#1}\vskip 0.4cm}
\ProgressGfxXSize = 1725
\ProgressGfxYSize = 120
\begin{document}
Page1
\progress{\thepage*100/\pageref{LastPage}}  % it should rturn 50
\pagebreak
Page2
\progress{\thepage*100/\pageref{LastPage}}  % it should rturn 100
\end{document}
```

Comment: related: [How can I define a mathematical function as a LaTeX macro?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147891/how-can-i-define-a-mathematical-function-as-a-latex-macro)

Comment: Or: [How to do simple calculation in Latex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87824/how-to-do-simple-calculation-in-latex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `refcount`. Note that the label is `LastPage` and not `Lastpage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lastpage,refcount}
\usepackage[draft,subsubsection]{progress}

\renewcommand{\ProgressDocOutput}[1]{%
  \vskip-0.6cm\ProgressDrawBar{#1}\vskip 0.4cm}
\ProgressGfxXSize = 1725
\ProgressGfxYSize = 120

\newcommand{\calcprogress}{%
  \progress{%
    \numexpr
      \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}=0
        0
      \else
        \thepage*100/\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}
      \fi
    \relax
  }%
}

\begin{document}
Page1
\calcprogress  % it should return 50

\pagebreak

Page2
\calcprogress  % it should return 100

\end{document}
```

Explanation: `\progress` wants a number that's stored in a count register, so `\numexpr` is good. We have to deal with the case `LastPage` has not yet been set, when `\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}` returns 0; in this case we return 0, otherwise we do the computation.