# Perform simple calculations on user-defined variables

Tags: calculations

In my document, I have a user-defined variable like:

```
 \newcommand{\MyNumber}{30}
```

Suppose, if I want to use a derivative of \MyNumber, it could be \MyNumber+10, 100-\MyNumber, 5*\MyNumber of \MyNumber/5, can that be done?

One step forward, if I have:

```
\newcommand{\MyNumberA}{30}

\newcommand{\MyNumberB}{60}
```

Can I use, \MyNumberA+\MyNumberB?

Comment: There are several solutions. For example, my package calculator.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I define a mathematical function as a LaTeX macro?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147891/how-can-i-define-a-mathematical-function-as-a-latex-macro)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use  `etex` capabilities for simple calculations:

```
\numexpr (\MyNumberA + 2* \MyNumberN)/3 \relax `
```

computes a weighted means of \MyNumberA and \MyNumberB.

Similarly, you can do calculations with dimensions, using `\dimexpr`.

Comment: You can add that you have to add `\the` if you want to print the result.

Comment: Thanks @karlkoeller, `\the\numexpr (2 + 2) \relax` even works within `siunitx` (e.g. `\SI{\the\numexpr (2 + 2) \relax}{\meter}`)

Comment: How do I store the value in another variable? Should I write `\newcommand{\MyNumberC}{\numexpr (\MyNumberA + 2* \MyNumberN)/3 \relax}`?

Answer (score 3):

You can do all of this using Plain TeX/LaTeX counters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\begin{document}
\obeylines%
\newcount\MyNumber%
\MyNumber=30%
\def\tp#1{\texttt{\string\MyNumber #1} =}%
\tp{} \the\MyNumber
\advance\MyNumber by 10\relax%
\tp{ + 10} \the\MyNumber
\multiply\MyNumber by 100\relax%
\tp{ * 100} \the\MyNumber

\medskip
Adding numbers:
\newcount\MyNumberA
\newcount\MyNumberB
\MyNumberA=30
\MyNumberB=60
\the\MyNumberA + \the\MyNumberB = \the\numexpr\MyNumberA + \MyNumberB\relax
\end{document}
```

> [image]