# Decimal on Divison

Tags: math-mode

The following example return value 0 at division of **\x** by **\y**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\x}{31}
\newcommand{\y}{45}
\begin{document}
    I need the decimal results of following division:
    \the\numexpr\x/\y\relax.
\end{document}
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: `\numexpr` returns an integer number and rounds. Therefore, the result of 31/45 is `1`, not `0`.

Comment: See the `fp` or `xfp` packages for real-number mathematics, for example.  I believe `pgf` based packages also provide such facilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}

\fpeval{31/45}

\fpeval{round(31/45,5)}

\end{document}
```

The toolbox of `xfp` is quite extensive.

[image]

If you need the comma instead of the decimal period, use `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp,siunitx}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\num{\fpeval{31/45}}

\num{\fpeval{round(31/45,5)}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\x}{31}
\newcommand{\y}{45}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\MyDivide[2]{\strip@pt\dimexpr\numexpr#1*65536/#2 sp\relax}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
    I need the decimal results of following division:
    \MyDivide{\x}{\y}
\end{document}
```

[image]

oops sorry I had interchanged `#1` and `#2` first. So:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. And if I wanna make another operation (+, - or *) with those number. How could be?

Comment: @AndreyVinajera perhaps start with answers [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15526/floating-point-calculations-in-latex) or [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167222/perform-simple-calculations-on-user-defined-variables)

Comment: @AnderyVinajera the canonical answer nowadays is probably to use the `xfp` package from LaTeX3 team, as in egreg's answer. It does computations with 16 decimal digits of precision and provides exp, log, sin, cos... My own `xint` computes in arbitrary precision and with fractions exactly, and has a `floating-point` mode which like `xfp` is set at 16 digits per default, but you can set it to 24 digits... caveat is that currently (April 2018) only sqrt is available as math function. `xintexpr`'s parser has very extended syntax allowing things such as `add(x(x+3)(x+5), x=10..20)`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex

\RequirePackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function mycalc (prec,n)
   tex.sprint ( string.format ( "%."..prec.."f" , n) )
end
\end{luacode}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%% Show 5 digits of prec. by default:
\newcommand\mycalc[2][5]{\directlua{mycalc(#1,#2)}}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\x}{31} 
\newcommand{\y}{45}

I need the decimal results of following division: \mycalc{\x/\y}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: @AndreyVinajera - Observe that the method used in this answer works for all arithmetic operations, not just division. Assuming `\a`, `\b`, and `\c` are suitably defined, you could write `\mycalc{\a^{\b}*\c}`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The `xlop` package 0.26 allows you to do French divisions like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}

\begin{document}
“french”  division:

\opdiv{31}{45}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

It can stop as soon as the period found

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}

\begin{document}
With inline mode:
\opdiv[maxdivstep=5,style=text]{31}{45}

Stop with period detection:
\opdiv[period,style=text]{31}{45}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Star macros allow calculations to be performed without displaying the result. In the case of division, the `\opdiv*{31}{45}{q}{r}` macro stores the quotient (q) and the rest (r) in two parameters.

Three macros allow a control about precision. They allow to approximate a number giving the rank of the approximation. There are `\opfloor` (default approximate value), `\opceil` (excess approximate value), and `\opround` (rounding)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}

\begin{document}

Approximation:
\opdiv*[maxdivstep=15]{31}{45}{q}{r}
 \opfloor{q}{7}{a}
 \opceil{q}{10}{b}
 \opround{q}{13}{c}

\opprint{a}

\opprint{b}

\opprint{c}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]