# How to write "loop" in the following PSTricks example?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{xfp,pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,linejoin=1](-2,-2)(2,2)
%%%
\def\mypoly#1#2{% #1: sides, #2: angles
\pnode(0,0){O}
\def\n{#1}
\def\goc{\fpeval{round(360/#1,2)}} %%  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425043/decimal-on-divison
\multido{\iA=1+1}{#1}{\pnode(1;\fpeval{#2+\iA*\goc}){A\iA}}
\pstProjection[PointName=,PointSymbol=none]{A1}{A2}{O}[K]
\pstTriangleOC[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]{A1}{A2}{A3}
\pspolygon(A1)(A2)(A3)(A4)(A5)%(A6)%(A7)%(A8)
\pstCircleOA[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white]{O}{K}}
%%%%%
\mypoly{5}{18}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Question:

You can see `\pspolygon(A1)(A2)(A3)(A4)(A5)%(A6)%(A7)%(A8)`

With \mypoly{5}{18} `n=5` , LaTeX print `\pspolygon(A1)(A2)(A3)(A4)(A5)`; \mypoly{4}{45} `n=4` , LaTeX print `\pspolygon(A1)(A2)(A3)(A4)`; ...

How can I do?

Comment: You can use `loop` of `TeX`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to automatically involve all of the vertices in the polygon. This can be achieved by building up the list of vertices in the same `\multido` in which you define the vertices.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{xfp,pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,linejoin=1](-2,-2)(2,2)
%%%
\def\mypoly#1#2{%
\pnode(0,0){O}
\def\n{#1}
\def\goc{\fpeval{round(360/#1,2)}} %%  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425043/decimal-on-divison
\edef\mypoly{}
\multido{\iA=1+1}{#1}{\pnode(1;\fpeval{#2+\iA*\goc}){A\iA}%
\xdef\mypoly{\mypoly(A\iA)}}
\pstProjection[PointName=,PointSymbol=none]{A1}{A2}{O}[K]
\pstTriangleOC[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]{A1}{A2}{A3}
\edef\temp{\noexpand\pspolygon\mypoly}
\temp
\pstCircleOA[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white]{O}{K}}
%%%%%
%\mypoly{5}{18}
%\mypoly{6}{18}
\mypoly{7}{18}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you may find it more convenient to define the full pic like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{xfp,pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\def\mypolypic#1#2{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,linejoin=1](-2,-2)(2,2)
%%%
\pnode(0,0){O}
\def\n{#1}
\def\goc{\fpeval{round(360/#1,2)}} %%  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425043/decimal-on-divison
\edef\mypoly{}
\multido{\iA=1+1}{#1}{\pnode(1;\fpeval{#2+\iA*\goc}){A\iA}%
\xdef\mypoly{\mypoly(A\iA)}}
\pstProjection[PointName=,PointSymbol=none]{A1}{A2}{O}[K]
\pstTriangleOC[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]{A1}{A2}{A3}
\edef\temp{\noexpand\pspolygon\mypoly}
\temp
\pstCircleOA[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white]{O}{K}
\end{pspicture}}
%%%%%
\multido{\iB=3+1}{8}{\noindent
\mypolypic{\iB}{18}\ifodd\iB\else\\\fi}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

no need for any loop. You should make things simpel and not complecated! Simply use `\psRing` and `\PstPolygon`. Can be extended
to any value `n` with simple geometry equations.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{xfp,pst-eucl,pst-poly}
\newcommand\myPoly[2][]{{%
  \psRing[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,#1](0,0){\fpeval{cos(1/#2*3.14)}}{1}%
  \PstPolygon[PolyNbSides=#2,PstPicture=false,PolyRotation=\fpeval{90/#2},#1]%  
}}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,linejoin=1](-2,-2)(2,2)
\myPoly[unit=2,PolyRotation=\fpeval{180/8}]{8}
\myPoly[fillcolor=blue!40]{5}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your simplification is differ from my thinking! Really, my code does not use `pst-poly` package (I have seen it before) and `\psRing` , both is difficult for `junior users` as myself. :-),

Comment: then calculate the inner and outer radius which is simple for a polygon.