# Perform spreadsheet-like calculations and display formula and result

Tags: calculations

Currently I am performing calculations using excel and manually formatting them for printing using an online LaTeX equation editor. The end result looks something like this:
[image]

As you may imagine this requires a lot of double-hadling of the parameters and, if any of the variables change, everything must be retyped. Is there any way where I could achieve a similar output directly through LaTeX?

I would like to be able to define the variables, some of which are calculated from other variables, and display the formulas, with both the parameters and the values shown.
I don't need to perform any complex mathematics. Typically +,-,*,/ and exponents is all that would be required though basic functions (sin, ln, log) may also be useful.

Comment: ...then you need to look at [How can I define a mathematical function as a LaTeX macro?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147891/5764)

Comment: I am using `tikz`/`pgfplots` package for such calculations. You may also like to look at the [`spreadtab`](http://ctan.org/pkg/spreadtab) package, it is probably already installed in your TeX distribution.

Comment: `spreadtab` should be able to handle this, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70860/can-latex-perform-calculation-like-excel-formula-table/70865

Comment: I have looked at `spreadtab` package it seems to be able to do the calculations I want but not display the formula used to generate the numbers too. Perhaps I would need to create a macro to extend spreadtab?

Answer (score 3):

I started working on it before JPi had answered, so I will post my solution anyways.

LuaTeX is ideal for this. For example, here is solution using ConTeXt (It should be easy to translate it to LaTeX).

```
\startluacode
  userdata = userdata or {}
  userdata.variables = 
    {
      m = 10,
      Cp = 30,
      T1 = 15,
      T2 = 20,
    }

  variables = userdata.variables

  variables.DeltaT = variables.T2 - variables.T1
  variables.Q = variables.m*variables.Cp*variables.DeltaT

  local function showRow(a,b,c)
      context("\\NC %s \\NC %s \\NC %s \\NC \\NR", a, b, c)
  end

  local function singleRow(a)
      context("\\NC[nc=3, align=middle] %s \\NC \\NR", a)
  end

  local format = string.format

  userdata.ShowVariables = function()
    context.startTABLE{setups="table:variables"}
    showRow("Parameter Value", "Units", "Description")
    showRow("$m$", format("\\unit{%s KiloGram}", variables.m), "Mass")
    showRow("$Cp$", format("\\unit{%s KiloJoule/Celsius KiloGram}", variables.Cp), "Heat Capacity")
    showRow("$T_1$", format("\\unit{%s Celsius}", variables.T1), "Initial Temperature")
    showRow("$T_2$", format("\\unit{%s Celsius}", variables.T2), "Final Temperature")
    singleRow(format("$ΔT = T_2 - T_1 = %s - %s = %s~[\\unit{Celsius}]$", variables.T2, variables.T1, variables.DeltaT))
    showRow("$ΔT$", format("\\unit{%s Celsius}", variables.DeltaT), "Temperature Difference")
    singleRow(format("$Q = m × Cp × ΔT = %s × %s × %s = %s~[\\unit{KiloJoule}]$", variables.m, variables.Cp, variables.DeltaT, variables.Q))
    showRow("$Q$", format("\\unit{%s KiloJoule}", variables.Q), "Heat")
    context.stopTABLE()
  end
\stopluacode

\startsetups table:variables
  \setupTABLE[frame=off, offset=0.25em]
  \setupTABLE[column][3][width=12em] 
  % Width needed, otherwise column span doesn't work
\stopsetups

\define\ShowVariables{\ctxlua{userdata.ShowVariables()}}

\starttext
\ShowVariables
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

I used a separate namespace `userdata` to avoid conflict with existing variable names.

Answer (score 2):

Easy with `lualatex:`

```
%% compile with lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
 function celsius(t)
  tex.sprint((t-32)*5/9)
  end
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand{\celsius}[1]{\luadirect{celsius(\luastring{#1})}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rr}
 50 & \celsius{50}\\
 -40 & \celsius{-40}
 \end{tabular}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- > Currently I am performing calculations using excel and manually
  >   formatting them for printing using an online LaTeX equation editor.
- **tranquillity**, LaTeX itself is the system for graphical representation of the math expression if we talk about math part of
  LaTeX. The most of programs that perform the calculations by LaTeX it
  needs to be the LaTeX text typed with special rules. Each program has its
  own rules. Then such a program parses the text, recognizes variables, their values and make the calculations. As an algorithm it always like the
  sequence of the following operations:
- Typset LaTeX text of the special type were is specially specified such
  data as variables, their values, output format and so on;
- launch the program that perform the cslculation.
- I wish to offer a different solution. It seems there is exactly what
  you are looking for. That is the program that build the LaTeX string
  of math expression that you type in plain text easily. It performs
  calculations with variables, saves result to file, analyzes errors
  connected not only with wrong syntax, but it help find and even avoid
  such errors as **loss of relevance (accuracy), and the possibility of
  accidental results** (infinity, not a number).
- That program is **AnEasyCalc**. Type in any search engin (without
  spaces) and you will find a lot of file storage servers when it can be
  downloaded.

You can find it also at developer's site:
  http://steamandwater.od.ua/AnEasyCalc/index.html

- This demo version is unlimited by the use time, but has a limmited
  functionality. The main restriction is the sting length that can not
  be more 32. If we abandon long names and indexes  fairly complex things can be calculated.

### Good luck)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand what you talk about in roughly the first part of your answer. Is it even relevant to the question at hand? The second half of your answer is not that clear to me either, but I can see a connection to the question. Your question suffers from somewhat confusing mark-up. Maybe you can make it more to the point and concise.

Comment: From reading [another answer of yours mentioning AnEasyCalc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249254/35864) I can't help but feel that this does the opposite of what the OP asks for.

Comment: That is so easy as aneasycalc is easy to use.

Comment: Sorry but the ENTER pressing momentaly sends the message. That is why the previous comment has appeared.)  Look at question please: TC says: "Currently I am performing calculations using excel and manually formatting them for printing using an online LaTeX equation editor." and it needs to  " a lot of double-hadling of the parameters and, if any of the variables change, everything must be retyped. " Than TC asks: "Is there any way where I could achieve a similar output directly through LaTeX? " MY ANSWER IS: try aneasycalc program thus it makes all as you want! What I have done wrong?