# Tikz plot of a (log-) normal quantile function and inverse error function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I want to plot the lognormal and normal quantile functions in tikz. To fix notation, let's refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution, which gives the quantile of the normal distribution as:

```
F^{-1}(p)=\mu +\sigma \Phi ^{-1}(p)=\mu +\sigma {\sqrt {2}}\,\operatorname {erf} ^{-1}(2p-1),\quad p\in (0,1).
```

The quantiles of the lognormal distribution are then given by the exponential  of `F^{-1}(p)`.

My problem thus reduces to plotting the inverse of the error function, which I do not know how to do.

Comment: Possibly taking the solutions to [Erf function in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107423/106162) and simply using the reciprocal does the job.