# Problem with curly brackets and \pgfmathsetmacro

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach

I want to create a loop over an false-position algorithm
But I have two problems with `\pgfmathsetmacro`.

```
(1) The curly parentheses does not allow `\pgfmathsetmacro` to evaluate
```

In the code below, my `\XM` will not be defined if I insert the curly parenthesis there. This problem prevent me from using `\foreach`

```
(2) If the variable is redefined, it plots from the new position instead of the 
value where the plot was issued.
```

This forces me to defined new variable which is not a good way.

What should I do ??

**Here is the code**

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\usepackage{tikz-dimline}   
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
% Adapted from the 'patterns' library: enlarged the distance between the lines from 4pt to 10pt
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{north east lines wide}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{10pt}{10pt}}{\pgfqpoint{9pt}{9pt}}%
{
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{9.1pt}{9.1pt}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
}

\tikzset{%
body/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,shape=rectangle,draw,thick,pattern=north east lines wide},
dimen/.style={<->,>=latex,thin,every rectangle node/.style={fill=white,midway,font=\sffamily}},
symmetry/.style={dashed,thin},
}

\definecolor{gray3}{RGB}{50, 50, 50}
\definecolor{gray2}{RGB}{100, 100, 100}
\definecolor{gray1}{RGB}{150, 150, 150}

\definecolor{red3}{RGB}{255, 0, 0}
\definecolor{red2}{RGB}{220, 70, 91}
\definecolor{red1}{RGB}{255, 120, 120}

\begin{document}

    %the plotting function
\def\FunctionF(#1){(sin(3*#1*180.0/3.1415)-0.1)}%
\newcommand*{\FunctionFGnuplot}{ (sin(3*x)-0.1)}%
\newcommand\XL{0.1}
\newcommand\XR{2.0}
%----two beginning points leftmost and rightnost
\pgfmathsetmacro{\YL}{\FunctionF(\XL)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\YR}{\FunctionF(\XR)}  

    \begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
trig format plots=rad,
axis lines = middle,
enlargelimits,
, ymin=-1,ymax=1.0, restrict y to domain=-3:3,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$, 
every axis x label/.style={
at={(ticklabel* cs:1.025)},
anchor=north east,
}
,every axis y label/.style={
at={(ticklabel* cs:1.025)},
anchor=east,
}
]

\addplot[color=blue,domain=\XL:\XR,line width = 1.0,samples=64]{ \FunctionFGnuplot};
%---two beginning points
\addplot[mark=*,color=blue] coordinates {(\XL,\YL)};
\addplot[mark=*,color=blue] coordinates {(\XR,\YR)};


%---the straight line joining two points. 
%   The x-intersection will be the new xm   


% Line1
\draw [line width = 0.25] (axis cs:\XL,\YL)--(axis cs:\XR,\YR);


%%------------------- Problem with  {}   here -----------------
%% Problem 1:
%% If I open the curly bracket below here \XM will not be defined no matter
%% where I close it


\pgfmathsetmacro{\XM}{  \XL - \YL* (\XR-\XL ) / (\YR-\YL)  }    ;
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\YM}{\FunctionF(\XM)}  ;
      %\addplot[mark=*,color=gray1] coordinates {(\XM,0)};
      \node[gray,below] at (axis cs:\XM,0){$x_m^1$};
    %----------------------------------------------------------------


    \addplot[mark=*,color=red1] coordinates {(\XM,\YM   )}; 

\draw [->,line width = 0.25] (axis cs:\XM,0) to   (axis cs:\XM,\YM/2);  
\draw [-, line width = 0.25] (axis cs:\XM,0) to   (axis cs:\XM,\YM);    

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Problem 2: Line1 is not drawn immeadiately when it was defined above.
%           But it wait until \XL was redefined here.
%           Instead of having a line joining two blue dots,
%           I got something else. 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\XLL}{ ifthenelse( \YL*\YM <0, \XL, \XM)};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\XRR}{ ifthenelse( \YL*\YM <0, \XM, \XR)}; 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\YLL}{ ifthenelse( \YL*\YM <0, \YL, \YM)};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\YRR}{ ifthenelse( \YL*\YM <0, \YM, \YR)}; 


    %----------------second loop
\draw [line width = 0.25] (axis cs:\XLL,\YLL)--(axis cs:\XRR,\YRR);
\pgfmathsetmacro{\XMM}{  \XLL - \YLL* (\XRR-\XLL ) / (\YRR-\YLL)  } ;
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\YMM}{\FunctionF(\XMM)}    ;
    %\addplot[mark=*,color=gray2] coordinates {(\XMM,0)};
          \node[gray,above] at (axis cs:\XMM,0){$x_m^2$};

    \addplot[mark=*,color=red2] coordinates {(\XMM,\YMM )}; 
\draw [->,line width = 0.25] (axis cs:\XMM,0) to   (axis cs:\XMM,\YMM/2);   
\draw [-, line width = 0.25] (axis cs:\XMM,0) to   (axis cs:\XMM,\YMM); 

\pgfmathsetmacro{\XLLL}{ ifthenelse( \YLL*\YMM <0, \XLL, \XMM)};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\XRRR}{ ifthenelse( \YLL*\YMM <0, \XMM, \XRR)};    
\pgfmathsetmacro{\YLLL}{ ifthenelse( \YLL*\YMM <0, \YLL, \YMM)};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\YRRR}{ ifthenelse( \YLL*\YMM <0, \YMM, \YRR)};    

%----------------third loop 

\draw [line width = 0.25] (axis cs:\XLLL,\YLLL)--(axis cs:\XRRR,\YRRR);
\pgfmathsetmacro{\XMMM}{  \XLLL - \YLLL* (\XRRR-\XLLL ) / (\YRRR-\YLLL)  }  ;
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\YMMM}{\FunctionF(\XMMM)}  ;

    %\addplot[mark=*,color=gray3] coordinates {(\XMMM,0)};  
              \node[gray, above right, node distance = 1cm] at (axis cs:\XMMM,0){$x_m^3$};
    \addplot[mark=*,color=red3] coordinates {(\XMMM,\YMMM   )}; 

\draw [->,line width = 0.25] (axis cs:\XMMM,0) to   (axis cs:\XMMM,\YMMM/2);    
\draw [-, line width = 0.25] (axis cs:\XMMM,0) to   (axis cs:\XMMM,\YMMM);      

\draw [line width = 0.25] (axis cs:\XLLL,\YLLL)--(axis cs:\XRRR,\YRRR); 


\pgfmathsetmacro{\XLLLL}{ ifthenelse( \YLLL*\YMMM <0, \XLLL, \XMMM)};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\XRRRR}{ ifthenelse( \YLLL*\YMMM <0, \XMMM, \XRRR)};   
\pgfmathsetmacro{\YLLLL}{ ifthenelse( \YLLL*\YMMM <0, \YLLL, \YMMM)};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\YRRRR}{ ifthenelse( \YLLL*\YMMM <0, \YMMM, \YRRR)};   
%----------------fourth loop    
\pgfmathsetmacro{\XMMMM}{  \XLLLL - \YLLLL* (\XRRRR-\XLLLL ) / (\YRRRR-\YLLLL)  }   ;


     \addplot[mark=*,color=black] coordinates {(\XMMMM,0)};
\end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you might want to reduce the code to something just related to your problem, the rest does not seem relevant to the problem you ask about.

Comment: There are to issues. The minor one is that all assignments and definitions by tikz, pgfplots, pgfmath etc are *local* to the current group (which is a good thing). This means that when you enclose a group of definitions into curly braces, they will not exist outside of the braces. The major issue in your approach is that `pgfplots` does not evaluate variables in `\draw` commands and the like immediately, but delays the `\draw`s until the end of the axis where the variables have changed/lost their values.

Comment: The solution: Expand variables in `\draw` statements immediately. For `foreach` loops there is a pgfplots replacement that does this implicitly. For details see ["\foreach not behaving in axis environment"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170664/foreach-not-behaving-in-axis-environment), ["Why doesn't a \foreach variable work in \draw in an \axis?"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165945/why-doesnt-a-foreach-variable-work-in-draw-in-an-axis) and/or ["Use macro to draw inside pgfplot/axis"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73390/use-macro-to-draw-inside-pgfplot-axis).