# Graphing a rational function and a vertical line using pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like the code that instructs TikZ to plot the graph for the rational function `y=(x^{2}+5x+6)/(x^{2}+2x-3)`. I tried using `addplot[very thin,blue]{frac(x^{2}+5x+6)/(x^{2}+2x-3)}`.  This graph has a vertical asymptote x = 1.  What is the code for plotting this line - as a dashed line - with arrowheads?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\begin{document}

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal image,
          xmax=8,ymax=7,
          axis lines=middle,
          restrict y to domain=-7:7,
          enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
          axis line style={latex-latex},
          ticklabel style={fill=white},
          ytick=\empty,
          xtick={-3}
          %xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
]
\addplot[domain=-10:10,mark=none,samples=10] {frac{x + 2}{x - 1} node [above left, yshift=3pt]{$\scriptstyle{y}=\frac{x^{2}+5x+6}{x^{2}+2x-3}$};
\draw [fill=white] (-3,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this answer help you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34201/12440

Comment: There has to be a better code for plotting this rational function. I do not know most of the commands in the code that you provided: `double y domain/.code 2 args={}` and `ejes/.style args={}`.  That code was given years ago.  There must be an updated version to pgfplots.

Comment: Just a remark: As far as I know, adding arrows on _both_ ends of an axis is mathematically wrong. Normally you only add an arrow on the end which points in the _positive_ direction (upwards and to the right, in your plot).

Comment: It is not wrong to put arrowheads at both ends. In textbooks, I almost always see each axis drawn with arrowheads at both ends.  In case arrowheads are not at both ends, there are no arrowheads drawn.

Comment: Okay, maybe the word "wrong" is too strong. However, I have never seen anyone put arrows on both ends, and in school and university I was taught that only the positive end should be marked in order to prevent confusion. Otherwise the arrows are pure decoration and convey no information at all. See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52515/standard-for-graph-axis-arrows

Comment: In what country was your high school?  I am from New York.  Here, we were told (in high school) that we would lose points if we did not draw arrowheads on both ends of each axis.  I agree with you that it is mostly decoration ... everybody knows that the axes extend in all four directions "to infinity."  I still like to have them.

Comment: I went to school and studied in Germany, but even online I haven't encountered that convention.

Answer (score 5):

With my version of PGFplots, the `\addplot` command you provide doesn't even compile, so I had to guess what you want to achieve. In PGFplots you can just write fractions like this: `1/(x^2)`.

With Matthew's comment to Jake's answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34201/12440) you can drawn an asymptote at `x=1` by using the key `vasymptote=1`. In order to reliably truncate the plot without using many samples (orange curve), you can plot the two parts separately, specifying the `domain` so that is ends slightly before `x=1` (black curve).

[image: Some curve]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\pgfplotsset{vasymptote/.style={
    before end axis/.append code={
        \draw[densely dashed] ({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:#1,0})
        -- ({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:#1,0});
    }
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={fill=white},
    ytick={-10,10},
    xtick={-3,-10,10},
    vasymptote=1,
]
% This doesn't clip to y=-10:10 nicely
% because there are too few samples near the asymptote:
\addplot[very thick, orange, domain=-10:10,samples=200, restrict y to domain=-10:10]
    {(x^2+5*x+6)/(x^2+2*x-3)};

% Draw the two parts separately with individual domains:
\addplot[samples=50,domain=-10:1-0.27] {(x^2+5*x+6)/(x^2+2*x-3)};
\addplot[samples=50,domain=1+0.33:10]  {(x^2+5*x+6)/(x^2+2*x-3)};

\draw [fill=white] (-3,0) circle [radius=1.5pt]; % What is this?
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now, I will reply to your code instead of our discussion on decorating the axes with arrowheads.   I am not familiar with the `\pgfplotsset{vasymptote/.style={}` command.  I would like to use the `draw[dashed]` command to draw a vertical asymptote, the equation of which is x = 1.  I would also like to use the `draw[dashed]` command to draw a horizontal asymptote, the equation of which is y = 1.  Unbelievably, I did not find the code in the manual for drawing lines.  Oh, I would like arrowheads on these lines.  I think it is something like `draw[dashed,<->]` but I got an error.

Comment: You asked me why I had the command `\draw [fill=white] (-3,0) circle [radius=1.5pt]`. The function has a removable discontinuity at -3.  That is the reason for having xtick{-3} in the code.  Can I have "-3" typeset in a smaller font such as scriptstyle?  How do I label the axes?  I would like to have "x" to be printed below and to the right of the right arrowhead, and I would like to have "y" to be printed above and to the right of the top arrowhead.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. For the tick font size you can use `tick style={font=\small}` or similar. Otherwise, please have a look at the PGFplots manual. Just try entering `texdoc pgfplots` in a terminal, or enter the same term into a search engine of your choice. There is a whole chapter called "Axis Descriptions" and a section called "Axis Lines" which explains everything with nice pictures and examples. If you get stuck, simply ask another question.

Answer (score 4):

Mark Wibrow's solution will produce a permanent catastrophic when `plotpoints=14*(2^n)+1` (for any non-negative integer `n`).

So the following solution can be used to overcome such an issue (just for fun).

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=20pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\def\f{(x+2)/(x-1)}

\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}[algebraic,plotpoints=1000,Dy=5,Dx=2]{->}(0,0)(-11,-30)(11,35){20cm}{20cm}
    \psset{linecolor=red}
    \psplot{-10}{0.9}{\f}
    \psplot{1.1}{10}{\f}
    \psset{linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue}
    \psline(1,-30)(1,35)
    \psline(-11,1)(11,1)
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, with PSTricks :O

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=20pt,yunit=20pt}
\begin{pspicture}*(-7.5,-7.5)(7.5,7.5)
  \psgrid[gridlabels=0,gridcolor=gray!25,subgridcolor=gray!10](-7,-7)(7,7)
  \psaxes[labels=none,ticksize=-2pt 2pt]{<->}(0,0)(-7,-7)(7,7)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
  \psplot[linecolor=blue,plotstyle=line,algebraic, yMaxValue=7,plotpoints=1000]
      {-7}{7}{(x^2+5*x+6)/(x^2+2*x-3)} 
  \psline[linestyle=dashed](1,-7)(1,7)
  \rput(4.5,4){$\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{x^2+5x+6}{x^2+2x-3}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It will fail when `plotpoints=14*(2^n)+1` for any positive integer `n`.

Comment: Non negative integers `n` (I meant).

Comment: Just out interest: is there some non-negative integer `n` for which `14*(2^n)+1=1000`?

Comment: No. There is not such `n`.

Comment: `n<21` is the upper bound.

Comment: Good, I was so _very_ concerned that when I used `plotpoints=1000` in my answer the plot would fail and the function would not appear. Then I would not have an image to post.

Answer (score 2):

All you need are a couple of addplot commands:

```
  \addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=1000]
  {(x^2+5*x+6)/(x^2+2*x-3)};
  \addplot[dashed, purple, latex-latex]
  coordinates{(1,-6) (1,6)};
```

The first one should plot your real function, the second one draws a vertical line using the coordinates. the `latex-latex` option adds `latex` arrow heads to either end. If you don't want arrow heads on both ends, just remove the appropriate `latex`. If you want to the vertical line to be longer, just replace -6 and 6 in the coordinates with something bigger, eg. -15 and 15.

here's a full example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal image,
          xmin=-8, xmax=8,
          ymin=-7, ymax=7,
          axis lines=middle,
          restrict y to domain=-10:10,
          enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
          axis line style={-latex},
          ytick=\empty,
          xtick={-3},
          %xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
  ]
  \addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=1000]
  {(x^2+5*x+6)/(x^2+2*x-3)};
  \addplot[dashed, purple, latex-latex]
  coordinates{(1,-6) (1,6)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```