# How do I draw a function in-between an interval?

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams, graphs

I am attempting to draw the function 1/((x+1)^{3/2})) on the interval -1,0. I want to include the vertical asymptote at x=-1 as well as shade the region between the two intervals. However, I keep getting errors with my current code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    standard/.style={
    axis line style = thick,
    trig format=rad,
    enlargelimits,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    enlarge x limits=0.15,
    enlarge y limits=0.15,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south east}
    }
}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[standard,
            xtick={-1,0},
            ytick=\empty,
            samples=1000,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            xmin=-1,xmax=0,
            ymin=-0.05,ymax=0.55]
        
\node[anchor=center,label=south west:$O$] at (axis cs:0,0){};
        
\addplot[domain={-1:0}]{1/((x+1)^{3/2})};
        
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I have managed to add the asymptote by using a newly defined command called vasymptote. My graph currently looks like this: [image]

This plot is without the line
\addplot[domain={-1:0}]{1/((x+1)^{3/2})};

The code for the above image is the same excpet it has the new command:

```
\newcommand{\vasymptote}[2][]{
    \draw [densely dashed,#1] ({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:#2,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:#2,0});
}
```

Comment: Try using () instead of {}...?

Comment: Do you mean: \addplot[red, domain={-1:0}](1/((x+1)^{3/2})));? @user202729

Comment: There are many examples: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=rational+plot

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202765/2099

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
axis line style=thick,
xmin=-1, xmax=0,
ymin=0, ymax=10,
enlarge x limits=0.15, enlarge y limits=0.15,
xtick={-1,0}, ytick=\empty,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)}, anchor=north west},
every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)}, anchor=south east},
axis on top,
]
\node[anchor=center, label=south west:$O$] at (axis cs:0,0){};
\addplot[domain=-1:0, fill=pink, y filter/.expression={x==-1?10:y}, samples=50, smooth]{1/((x+1)^(3/2))} \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with curve and fill under]