# Create asymptote handling pgfplots key

Tags: pgfplots, pgfkeys

#### I'm looking for an easy way to handle asymptotes well in pgfplots.

I recently saw [Asymptotes in a plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34197/asymptotes-in-a-plot#comment182604_34201) which has lead to me being able to create the following

```
vasym/.style={
    y filter/.expression = {abs(x-#1)<0.01 ? inf:y},
    before end axis/.append code={
        \draw[densely dashed] ({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:#1,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:#1,0});
    }
}
```

Plot of (x+1)/(x-1) using the key `vasym=1` in the axis.
[image]

However there are a few changes I'd like to make, but have no idea how to do. I'm hoping that someone out here might be able to help

#### Wishlist

1. I think it makes more sense to use the key in the `\addplot+` options
2. Follow up to (1): it would be nice if the asymptote line grabbed the colour of the corresponding function
3. It would be nice if the filter actually got rid of the plot for that region
4. It would be nice if the filter could be based on something like 0.005 * *plot range*
5. Ability to use multiple asymptotes (for functions like `tan(x)`)
6. A similar horizontal asymptote

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    no marks,samples=101,axis lines=middle,
    vasym/.style={
        y filter/.expression = {abs(x-#1)<0.01 ? inf:y},
        before end axis/.append code={
            \draw[densely dashed] ({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:#1,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {axis cs:#1,0});
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                domain=0:1.5,
                vasym=1
            ]
            \addplot+[red]{(x+1)/(x-1)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

#### Horizontal asymptote explained

For functions with a horizontal asymptote we really just want

- a horizontal line at a specified y value
- with the correct colour
- specified in the `\addplot+` options
  [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

1. Can be achieved by replacing `before end axis/.append code` by `xecute at end plot visualization`.
2. Can be achieved by giving the asymptote the `current plot style`.
3. Can be achieved by adding `unbounded coords=jump`.
4. This value is stored in the pgf key `asy interval` which you can adjust.
5. Added a proposal.
6. Added a proposal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{asy interval/.initial=0.01,
    no marks,samples=101,axis lines=middle,
    vasym/.style={unbounded coords=jump,%<-added
        /utils/exec={\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {#1}
        {\ifnum\Y=1
         \xdef\myfilter{abs(x-\X)<\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/asy interval}}
        \else
         \xdef\myfilter{\myfilter || abs(x-\X)<\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/asy interval}} 
        \fi}},
        y filter/.expression = {(\myfilter) ? inf:y},
        execute at end plot visualization={%<-changed
            \begin{scope}
            \clip (rel axis cs:0,0) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1);
            \foreach \X in {#1}
            {\draw[current plot style,densely dashed%<-added
            ] ({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {axis cs:\X,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,1} -|
            {axis cs:\X,0});}
            \end{scope}
        }
    },
    hasym/.style={unbounded coords=jump,%<-added
        execute at end plot visualization={
            \begin{scope}
            \clip (rel axis cs:0,0) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1);
            \foreach \Y in {#1}
            {\draw[current plot style,densely dashed] ({rel axis cs:0,0} |- {axis
            cs:0,\Y}) -- ({rel axis cs:1,0} |- {axis cs:0,\Y});}
            \end{scope}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=0:1.5]
            \addplot+[red,vasym={-0.2,0.6,1}]{(x+1)/((x-0.6)*(x-1))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ymin=-4,ymax=6,domain=-1.5:1.5]
            \addplot[blue,hasym=1]{1+1/x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll go through the wishlist:
 1. Nailed it! :D
 2. _missing_
 3. Got that too!
 4. missing_
 5. Just added this, can you also do this?
 6. Horizontal as for `\addplot+[vasym=0]{1/x+5};` there's a horizontal asymp. for y=5

Comment: @tecosaur Please see my update.

Comment: Great! I've updated the question re: the horizontal asymptope. Other than that and (4) you've got it! I'll probably just wait a bit and see if anybody puts in an answer that gets them all, if nobody does then I'll just mark your's as the answer

Comment: One note on (4), I'm really just looking for something better than `abs(x-#1)<0.015 ?`, idealy it would be detect when y-value goes outside range, but any improvement is welcome!

Comment: @tecosaur I managed to achieve most things but 5 is more tricky.

Comment: Could you do something like have `vasyn` accept n arguments?

Comment: @tecosaur This does not buy us much here, I am afraid. You need to add the codes for the lines and combine the filters.

Comment: Would there be a way to have something like `vasym={1,2,3,4}` and then use that to construct `abs(x-1)<0.01 ? abs(x-2)<0.01 ? abs(x-3)<0.01 ...` and `execute at end plot visualization/.append`?

Comment: @tecosaur Something along those lines works, please see the edit.

Comment: That's fantastic! I don't think I could be happier :) Thanks

Comment: Ahhh. One final tweak — would it be possible to do a quick test to only draw asymptotes within the range of the graph? This is because I've changed to `clip mode=individual` and I'd like to prevent asymptotes from being drawn outside of the graph.

Comment: @tecosaur You only need to add `\clip (rel axis cs:0,0) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1);` inside `execute at end plot visualization={...}`. I added that.

Comment: Thanks :) _15charminimum..._

Comment: someone suggested an edit to put ´\clip´ in a `scope` environment.

Comment: @naphaneal that was me. Without that, it had adverse effects on other modifications I'd made to pgfplots.

Comment: @tecosaur OK, I added them. Before I rejected the edit since if one only adds other plots, then obviously nothing goes wrong without the scopes.

Comment: This affected me because I was also adding out-of-plot arrows, I don't know how many people who look at this are likely to have something similar going on but I thought better safe than sorry.

Comment: @tecosaur I see. Yes, it does not hurt to add these scopes, I think.